# ERROR TypeError: iconName.split is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular7

can not display svgIcon. i give iconName as input in svgIcon.

Name, Price is display work properly if remove `<mat-icon>`.

with  show me error like below:

> TypeError: iconName.split is not a function
>       at MatIcon.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js.MatIcon._splitIconName

**app.component.ts**

```
 getList(): ItemModel[] {

    const dataList: ItemModel[] = [];

    // let dataKey: string[] = [];

    const tempSanitizer = this.sanitizer;

    const tempService = this.service;

    Object.keys(this.service.dataSource).forEach( (key: string) => {

      dataList.push(this.service.dataSource[key]);

      // if (!tempService.dataSource.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //   console.log(key);
      // }
      // console.log(tempService.dataSource[key].icon);
      this.iconRegistery.addSvgIcon(

        key,

        tempSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(tempService.dataSource[key].icon)

      );

      }
    );

  return dataList;
```

}

**app.component.html**

```
<app-grid-beer [title]="'Top Weekly'" [itemList]="getList()"></app-grid-beer>
<!-- [dataSource]="" -->
    <app-grid-beer [title]="'Ever Green'" [itemList]="getList()"></app-grid-beer>
```

**grid-beer.component.html**

```
 <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of itemList">

      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="5px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">

        <mat-icon [svgIcon]="item.id" class="section-icon-height"></mat-icon>

        <span>{{item.id}}</span>

        <mat-label class="subtitle-1">{{item ? item.name : ''}}</mat-label>

        <label class="h6-header"><mat-icon svgIcon="rupee" class="rupee-icon"></mat-icon>{{item ? item.price : '' }}</label>

      </div>

    </mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: You are passing `item.id` to `[svgIcon]`, which actually expects a string

Comment: item.id type is string.

Comment: Do you return a list at all, I dont see a return statement?

Comment: I still think @TusharWalzade is right and `item.id` is not a string. Can you `console.log(typeof item.id)` to make entirely sure? Alternatively, show us how `ItemModel` is defined.

Comment: Try: `npm install`?